# Block Covariance Matrix - Positive Definite? (Quadratic Optimization)

Tags: quadratic-forms, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a covariance matrix C. I have then formulated an quadratic optimization problem that involves the following matrix in the quadratic form:

> [ C  C ]
>   [ C  C ]

However, the quadratic solver complains that this matrix is not positive definite. I can also reformulate the optimization problem so that it uses the following matrix in quadratic form:

> [ C -C ]
>   [-C  C ]

This matrix is also not positive definite. Now, I know that the problem I am trying to solve might not be possible to set up for quadratic optimization. However, I was wondering if maybe someone encountered a similar setup before, and can give me any hints? Maybe reformulate the problem? Or do some approximation? Make the matrix positive definite somehow? I know, now very clear, but I don't know what else I could add. Thank you!

Comment: I think it'd be clearer if you write the optimization problem.

Comment: @Shamisen min (a_T * x + 1/2 * x_T * M * x), where x <= 0, a - real valued vector, M = [ C, -C; -C, C ], and C is some covariance matrix (symmetric positive definite).

Comment: @MoritzFirsching The synonymization of [tag:qcqp] and [tag:quadratic-programming] - with quadratic-programming as the master tag - was [recently suggested on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags/4147#4147).  As far as I can tell, you are the creator of one of these two tags. So I wanted to let you know in case you have something to add to the discussion on meta. Feel free to ping me here or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2019/3/4) to let me know that you've seen this message and I can remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C$ is positive semidefinite, then so is $\begin{bmatrix} C & C\\ C & C\end{bmatrix}$ for the simple reason that it is nothing but the Kronecker product of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with $C$.

*EDIT*

For those who don't like Kronecker products, here is an alternative proof using block-matrices:

Since $C>0$, we can write $C^{1/2}$. Then, we can write
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} C & C\\ C & C\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} C^{1/2} & 0\\ C^{1/2} & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} C^{1/2} & C^{1/2}\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
which is a Gram matrix, hence semidefinite.

Comment: Strange, then why is my optimization package complaining it's not either positive definite, nor positive semi-definite? Are you sure? (Sorry for this lame question!)

Comment: please see above comment. also, here it seems like there are additional conditions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391852/positive-semidefiniteness-of-a-block-matrix-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices

Comment: @akuz: my answer addresses what you wrote in the question. I just proved the said matrix to be semidefinite but given your comment it seems that you are not convinced :-) please read the wikipedia page on Kronecker products to feel more convinced :-)

Comment: Thanks @Suvrit a lot for your answer. I will check the details, sorry I'm not too familiar with this subject. All I'm saying is that when I specify [ C C; C C ] matrix in my optimization routine (joptimizer), it complains it's not positive (semi-)definite. That might be a bug in their code too...

Comment: It's *semi*definite, so it means there is an eigenvalue which is exactly zero. If your optimization routine computes a matrix factorization, it might be the case that numerical errors perturb an eigenvalue to $-10^{-16}$ or the like. It would be best if you reformulated the problem deflating manually out the zero subspace (which you can compute explicitly).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you are right - numerical error is detected as small negative eigenvalues within the optimization package... I will check if there is a way to set a larger tolerance. But if not, how would I deflate the problem? I know how I could deflate the matrix, for example by doing SVD, but then I would need to translate my optimization problem in that space... Hopefully I can just increase the tolerance or error

Comment: Let's say I have a problem $min\, m^T x + 0.5 x^T M x$ - how would you reformulate it fir a deflated matrix M'?

Comment: Change basis everywhere to make a row and a column of zeros in $M$, then remove said row/column from everything.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni but won't it change the solution of the optimization problem?

Comment: @akuz: to avoid worrying about this loss of strict positivity, try solving $\min m^Tx + (1/2)x^T(M + \epsilon I)x$, where $\epsilon$ is tiny. This will mean, $[C+\epsilon I, C; C, C+\epsilon I]$ for you.

Comment: @akuz To understand what happens after diagonalization, think about the "test problem" $\min_{x,y} ax+by+dx^2$, that you get for $m=[a;b]$, $M=\begin{bmatrix}d & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. If $b\neq 0$, then the problem was ill-posed to start with and has no minimum. If $b=0$, then you can remove $y$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thank you! I will try to do change of basis for the entire problem.